# Remove some string to sum up by RID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with this kind of selection. I have try many statement but can't find the answers that I want to get. Below is the example of big table:

| RID | LID | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B987.1 | F123 | 23 |
| B987.2 | F537 | 76 |
| B674.1 | F956 | 34 |
| B345.1 | F264 | 50 |
| B765.1 | F874 | 8 |
| B765.2 | F358 | 9 |

The question is I want to remove all the behind `.%`, then empty or null to meet the same `RID` then sum up the `QTY` by RID. The result must be like this:

| RID | LID | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B987 |  | 99 |
| B674 | F956 | 34 |
| B345 | F264 | 50 |
| B765 |  | 17 |

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem? It may be useful to solve your problem with some simple tweak. @Jessica

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get the answer you are looking for. I make an assumption there would be decimal and numbers only towards the end of the string in RID.

```
select substring(rid,0,patindex('%.%',rid)) as rid
       ,case when count(*)=1 then max(lid) else '' end as lid
       ,sum(qty) as qty
  from t
group by substring(rid,0,patindex('%.%',rid)) 


Output
+------+------+-----+
| rid  | lid  | qty |
+------+------+-----+
| B345 | F264 |  50 |
| B674 | F956 |  34 |
| B765 |      |  17 |
| B987 |      |  99 |
+------+------+-----+
```

dbfiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04bd7e0f90adacc0943dfc916e965e72